# Controlling the order of points in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rpy2

I'm plotting a dense scatter plot in ggplot2 where each point might be labeled by a different color:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500))
df$y = rnorm(500)*0.1 + df$x
df$label <- c("a")
df$label[50] <- "point"
df$size <- 2

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size))
```

When I do this, the scatter point labeled "point" (green) is plotted on top of the red points which have the label "a". What controls this z ordering in ggplot, i.e. what controls which point is on top of which?

For example, what if I wanted all the "a" points to be on top of all the points labeled "point" (meaning they would sometimes partially or fully hide that point)? Does this depend on alphanumerical ordering of labels?

I'd like to find a solution that can be translated easily to rpy2.

Comment: The [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29325361/210945) is the best. @user248237dfsf, perhaps you could select an accepted answer?

Answer (score 68):

**2016 Update:**

The order aesthetic [has been deprecated](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases), so at this point the easiest approach is to sort the data.frame so that the green point is at the bottom, and is plotted last.  If you don't want to alter the original data.frame, you can sort it during the ggplot call - here's an example that uses `%>%` and `arrange` from the dplyr package to do the on-the-fly sorting:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(df %>%
         arrange(label),
       aes(x = x, y = y, color = label, size = size)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**Original 2015 answer for ggplot2 versions < 2.0.0**

In ggplot2, you can use the [order aesthetic](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html) to specify the order in which points are plotted. The last ones plotted will appear on top. To apply this, you can create a variable holding the order in which you'd like points to be drawn.

To put the green dot on top by plotting it after the others:

```
df$order <- ifelse(df$label=="a", 1, 2)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size, order=order))
```

Or to plot the green dot first and bury it, plot the points in the opposite order:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size, order=-order))
```

For this simple example, you can skip creating a new sorting variable and just coerce the `label` variable to a factor and then a numeric:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size, order=as.numeric(factor(df$label))))
```

Comment: I guess this is pretty new? It's a much better answer than all of the others.

Comment: @naught101 I'm glad you scrolled down to find this answer as it may take a while to bubble up the list. Based on various blog posts, the `order` aesthetic seems to have been around since at least 2009 or 2010.

Comment: @SamFrike I failed reproducing your solution using exact the same code, seems like the order aesthetic is ignored. I am using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) and x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 platform. Any idea concerning this issue? Thanks

Comment: @ChriiSchee thanks for noting this.  I see that the `order` aesthetic has unfortunately been deprecated from ggplot2, so I've updated the answer to reflect what I think is the next best option.

Comment: I'm using R4.2.2, ggplot2_3.4.1, and dplyr_1.1.0. When I do the `%>%` call in the `ggplot()` call, it doesn't work. But if I do it in the line before, it does. Any idea what, if anything, has changed?

Answer (score 67):

`ggplot2` will create plots layer-by-layer and within each layer, the plotting order is defined by the `geom` type. The default is to plot in the order that they appear in the `data`.

Where this is different, it is noted. For example

> ### `geom_line`
>
> Connect observations, ordered by x value.

and

> ### `geom_path`
>
> Connect observations in data order

---

There are also [known issues regarding the ordering of `factors`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/721), and it is interesting to note  the response of the package author Hadley

> The display of a plot should be invariant to the order of the data frame - anything else is a bug.

---

This quote in mind, a layer is drawn in the specified order, so overplotting *can* be an issue, especially when creating dense scatter plots. So if you want a consistent plot (and not one that relies on the order in the data frame) you need to think a bit more.

---

### Create a second layer

If you want certain values to appear above other values, you can use the `subset` argument to create a second layer to definitely be drawn afterwards. You will need to explicitly load the `plyr` package so `.()` will work.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500))
df$y = rnorm(500)*0.1 + df$x
df$label <- c("a")
df$label[50] <- "point"
df$size <- 2
library(plyr)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = label, size = size)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = label, size = size), 
             subset = .(label == 'point'))
```

[image]

### **Update**

In `ggplot2_2.0.0`, the `subset` argument is deprecated. Use e.g. `base::subset` to select relevant data specified in the `data` argument. And no need to load `plyr`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = label,  size = size)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, label == 'point'),
             aes(x = x, y = y, color = label, size = size))
```

---

### Or use `alpha`

Another approach to avoid the problem of overplotting would be to set the `alpha` (transparancy) of the points. This will not be as effective as the explicit second layer approach above, however, with judicious use of `scale_alpha_manual` you should be able to get something to work.

eg

```
# set alpha = 1 (no transparency) for your point(s) of interest
# and a low value otherwise
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size,alpha = label)) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(guide='none', values = list(a = 0.2, point = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. geom_path is super valuable here... this post is interesting as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/OuuYottSVwQ

Answer (score 24):

The fundamental question here can be rephrased like this:

> **How do I control the layers of my plot?**

In the 'ggplot2' package, you can do this quickly by splitting each different layer into a different command.  Thinking in terms of layers takes a little bit of practice, but it essentially comes down to what you want plotted on top of other things.  You build from the background upwards.

**Prep**: Prepare the sample data.  This step is only necessary for this example, because we don't have real data to work with.

```
# Establish random seed to make data reproducible.
set.seed(1)

# Generate sample data.
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500))
df$y = rnorm(500)*0.1 + df$x

# Initialize 'label' and 'size' default values.
df$label <- "a"
df$size <- 2

# Label and size our "special" point.
df$label[50] <- "point"
df$size[50] <- 4
```

You may notice that I've added a different size to the example just to make the layer difference clearer.

**Step 1**: Separate your data into layers.  Always do this BEFORE you use the 'ggplot' function.  Too many people get stuck by trying to do data manipulation from with the 'ggplot' functions.  Here, we want to create two layers: one with the "a" labels and one with the "point" labels.

```
df_layer_1 <- df[df$label=="a",]
df_layer_2 <- df[df$label=="point",]
```

You could do this with other functions, but I'm just quickly using the data frame matching logic to pull the data.

**Step 2**: Plot the data as layers.  We want to plot all of the "a" data first and then plot all the "point" data.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(
        data=df_layer_1,
        aes(x=x, y=y), 
        colour="orange", 
        size=df_layer_1$size) +
    geom_point(
        data=df_layer_2, 
        aes(x=x, y=y), 
        colour="blue", 
        size=df_layer_2$size)
```

[image: demo chart]

Notice that the base plot layer `ggplot()` has no data assigned.  This is important, because we are going to override the data for each layer.  Then, we have two separate point geometry layers `geom_point(...)` that use their own specifications.  The x and y axis will be shared, but we will use different data, colors, and sizes.

It is important to move the colour and size specifications outside of the `aes(...)` function, so we can specify these values literally.  Otherwise, the 'ggplot' function will usually assign colors and sizes according to the levels found in the data.  For instance, if you have size values of 2 and 5 in the data, it will assign a default size to any occurrences of the value 2 and will assign some larger size to any occurrences of the value 5.  **An 'aes' function specification will not use the values 2 and 5 for the sizes.**  The same goes for colors.  I have exact sizes and colors that I want to use, so I move those arguments into the 'geom_plot' function itself.  Also, any specifications in the 'aes' function will be put into the legend, which can be really useless.

**Final note**: In this example, you could achieve the wanted result in many ways, but it is important to understand how 'ggplot2' layers work in order to get the most out of your 'ggplot' charts.  As long as you separate your data into different layers before you call the 'ggplot' functions, you have a lot of control over how things will be graphed on the screen.

Comment: your second solution with layers is nice but there is no legend unfortunately for the colored points

Answer (score 10):

It's plotted in order of the rows in the data.frame. Try this:

```
df2 <- rbind(df[-50,],df[50,])
ggplot(df2) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size=size))
```

As you see the green point is drawn last, since it represents the last row of the data.frame.

Here is a way to order the data.frame to have the green point drawn first:

```
df2 <- df[order(-as.numeric(factor(df$label))),]
```

Comment: When I try your code, the green point is still on top of all the red. Is there a way to just change the z order without altering the dataframe? I just want certain points to be on top of others in a very dense scatter

Comment: You should have set the random seed to make your question reproducible. Just order the data.frame by `label` before passing it to `ggplot`. If you want the green point drawn first, order the data.frame so that rows with label `point` are on top of the data.frame.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to translate this `df[order(-as.numeric(factor(df$label))),]` into Rpy2 syntax (I am using rpy2, not R directly).

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about rpy2. You could use `df[order(df$label,decreasing=TRUE),]`, which should do the same.