# How do I bring a specific point (that I've made a different color) to the front of and R scatter plot?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I've made a scatterplot in R using:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x2~x1, pch=20, col=df$colour, cex=1.5, xlim=c(-4,16), ylim=c(-4,16))
with(df, text(x2~x1, labels = df$gene, pos = 4))
plot(x4~x3, pch=20, col=df$colour, cex=1.5, xlim=c(-4,16), ylim=c(-4,16))
with(df, text(x4~x3, labels = df$gene, pos = 4))
```

and I get something close to what i want, but i want the Red point of interest to be at the top of the stack in the second image.  I've tried re-ordering the dataframe to have the single point both first and last in the dataframe but it doesn't alter the image, the point of interst is still hidden in the second plot.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!
[image: image of two scatter plots]

Comment: If you're willing to use the ggplot2 package to make your charts, you can use the `order` aesthetic to specify point plotting order.  Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706281/controlling-order-of-points-in-ggplot2-in-r/29325361#29325361

Comment: Thanks Sam, i'll check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the point using `points` after calling the plot:

```
y1 <- x1[df$coulour=="red"]
y2 <- x2[df$coulour=="red"]
y3 <- x3[df$coulour=="red"]
y4 <- x4[df$coulour=="red"]

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(x2~x1, pch=20, col=df$colour, cex=1.5, xlim=c(-4,16), ylim=c(-4,16))
points(y2~y1, pch=20, col="red", cex=1.5)
with(df, text(x2~x1, labels = df$gene, pos = 4))

plot(x4~x3, pch=20, col=df$colour, cex=1.5, xlim=c(-4,16), ylim=c(-4,16))
points(y4~y3, pch=20, col="red", cex=1.5)
with(df, text(x4~x3, labels = df$gene, pos = 4))
```

Comment: That's perfect Sam, thanks for the advice.  Also thanks for the link above, I didn't come across it before posting the question.