# How to control which factor is plotted first in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = runif(n = 10000, min = 0, max = 1), y = 
rnorm(10000, sd = 0.2), type = "d1")
d2 <- data.frame(x = runif(n = 10000, min = 0, max = 1), y = 
rnorm(10000, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.2), type = "d2")
all_d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(all_d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = type)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Here you can see that `d2` points are plotted over the `d1` points. So I try changing things using `forcats::fct_relevel`

```
all_d_other <- all_d
all_d_other$type <- forcats::fct_relevel(all_d_other$type, "d2", "d1")
ggplot(all_d_other, aes(x = x, y = y, color = type)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

And `d2` points are still on top of the `d1` points. Is there a way to change it so that the `d1` points are on top of the `d2` points?

Comment: did you try plain base `?relevel`?  Worst case, you can add a separate `+geom_point()` for the d1, which will force them to be plotted second (on top)

Comment: R 3.4.2, ggplot2 2.2.1.9000

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, I didn't try base "relevel", as the "levels" seem to be modified as I expected, and also shown by the change in colors

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706281/controlling-order-of-points-in-ggplot2-in-r, apparently draw order is affected by the current order of your dataframe rather than the factor levels. This probably counts as a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your sort order so that the points you want on top are in the last rows of the dataframe.

```
all_d <- all_d[order(all_d$type, decreasing=TRUE),]

ggplot(all_d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = type)) + 
  geom_point()
```

For other ways to sort, see [`dplyr::arrange`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/arrange) or the very fast [`data.table::setorder`.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/setorder)

#### Another solution, somewhat hacky:

You can just re-draw your d1's so they show on top.

```
ggplot(all_d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = type)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=all_d[all_d$type=='d1',]) # re-draw d1's
```

#### Result (either way)

[image]

Comment: That would work, but feels hackish. Ideally there is a reordering of factors that just makes it "work".

Comment: @rmflight how about now?