# ggplot2 Line graphs in R: Plotting dependent variable on y axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the vertical concentration profile of a pollutant. By convention, altitude is plotted on the vertical axis, and concentration is on the x (even though altitude is the independent variable). When plotting the concentrations for pollutants that do not fit a one-to-one function, R connects the points in a most annoying zig-zag pattern, instead of connecting them in order by altitude.

[image]

I tried changing the concentration values to factors, with levels based on altitude values:

```
concSummary$value <- factor(concSummary$value, levels = 
                            concSummary$value[order(concSummary$altitude)])
```

But this didn't seem to work.
Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Someone posted a useful solution here: [controlling order of points in ggplot2 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706281/controlling-order-of-points-in-ggplot2-in-r)

Using geom_path() instead of geom_point() tells R to connect points in the order in which they appear in a dataframe. This happened to work for me because the data were ordered by altitude.