# Controlling order of points in ggplotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

Consider the problem (and the reproducable example) given in [controlling order of points in ggplot2 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706281/controlling-order-of-points-in-ggplot2-in-r).

The solution provided there (first order the data.frame, then plot) is working also for me. However, when I want to view the resulting plot using `plotly::ggplotly()` the order of points is messed up again. Anybody an idea how to keep the order of points in the plotly graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I find that plotly creates the right order in this particular example even without changing the plot/ data frame in a first place.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500),  label = 'a', stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% mutate(y = rnorm(500)*0.1 + x)
mydf$label[50] <- "point"

ggplot(mydf) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label, size = label)) + 
  scale_size_manual(values = c(a = 0.1,point = 2))

plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]

The safer option may probably be [@Dinre 's answer of your aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15816316/7941188) - separate your data to different layers first. I am using the suggested quick base R subset as in the answer, but you can also split using `split` or with tidyverse functions.

```
df_layer_1 <- mydf[mydf$label=="a",]
df_layer_2 <- mydf[mydf$label=="point",]

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df_layer_1, mapping = aes(x, y), colour="orange", size = .1) +
  geom_point(data=df_layer_2, aes(x, y), colour="blue", size = 2)

plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.0  ggplot2_3.2.0
```